# Handling ViewState this way in case it's null smells

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a more concise way to handle state management for my Total Count property?

```
    const string TOTAL_COUNT_KEY = "totalCount";
    private int TotalCount
    {
        get
        {
            int safeInt = 0;
            if (ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] != null)
                safeInt = (int)ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY];
            return safeInt;
        }
        set { ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] = value; }
    }
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simplify it to something like:

```
int TotalCount {
   get { return (int?)ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] ?? 0; }
   set { ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] = value; }
}
```

Anything more than that and you should probably consider extracting this to a reusable method of some kind.

Comment: Would this not crash with `InvalidCastException` if you call get before any value is set? I think it's safer to use `return (ViewState[TotalCountKey] as int?) ?? 0`, but I wouldn't bet money on it without checking first.

Comment: @kai `ViewState` is a `StateBag`. Testing this with a `StateBag` instead of a `Dictionary<string, object>`, there is no exception. I can get the default value, I can set a value, and I can get a value that I've set.

Comment: @kai keep in mind that casting a null value does not throw an exception unless you are casting it to a non-nullable type.

Comment: ah, in that case nevermind! although I personally prefer `as`, especially when used with the `??` operator.

Comment: @kai (sorry, replying to old comment). `as` is for cases when you may or may not have something of the particular type. In this case, we are asserting that if there is a value, it must be an integer, and if there is not a value, then we will default it to zero. If you used `as` in this situation, then you would get zero back if something other than an integer was put in the collection under that key. That may or may not be desirable in some case, but since in this case it represents a program error if there is a non-integer in the collection, you should use a cast.